# Error while installing phonegap version 2.0.0 on xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to install new phonegap version 2.0.0 with steps given in the following link:-

```
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS
```

But when I the run the ./create command i get following error:-

```
/Volumes/Cordova-2.0.0/bin/replaces: line 28: tmpFile: Read-only file system
mv: tmpFile: No such file or directory
```

And when i launch the xcode.proj from my folder location, i am not getting my project name as the target in the list (the drop down contains '**TESTING**', 'CordovaLib', 'CordovaLibApp')
and i am not getting the info plist file also.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have xcode closed when you do the ./create?

Comment: You don't need to `sudo`, just make sure you set the project path under your User folder. Also, why don't you use 2.1 since it is out now. It provides much better support for iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo` and provide admin credentials, like:

```
sudo ./create
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the error that happens in 2.0 when you try to create a project with a space in name or path. This was fixed in 2.1 (or choose a path & name without a space)